# Changing Chart Colors in Object Editor Based on a condition

Tags: palantir-foundry

Because my many to many relationship has too many links, I have to make my chart within the object view editor. (not sure if there is another way) However, how do I make it so if a value is above 80 on my chart, it changes to a different color? I want one bar on my chart to be a certain color. I attempted to change the YAML to make a different color, but no luck.

Thanks

YAML config:

colors:
- result: pick_any_value (obj)
color:
type: conditional
condition:
- if: 'value > 80'
then: green
- else: yellow
- {}

Comment: Can you be more specific about what error / limitation in which application is causing you to have to use the object view editor? What were you trying before that wasn't working?

Comment: When I make a chart in the Workshop app and click get linked objects it says in current value: "the number of results returned in a many to many search around exceeded configured limts. The workaround is to make the chart in object view and then make a widget in workshop to display the chart. However, when I make the chart in object view editor, I'm trying to manipulate the YAML or use anything to make it so my chart bar graph makes a certain color on a certain condition. IE: when a value is above 80 turn the bar green..ect. @ontologize

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think there are two separate things going on here: (1) the limit on many-to-many search-around results; (2) creating a chart with the particular display properties you want.

For (1), in general I would advise that you use the newer, more performant and more scalable OSv2 instead of OSv1 for the ontology backing store. This should let you do larger scale search-arounds. That said, I suspect the warning message you received is application-specific and not a result of the backing store used for these objects types and link types.

For (2) the only way I can think of doing the color-by-threshold in the ontology layer is to use a [Vega Plot in Quiver](https://www.palantir.com/docs/foundry/quiver/cards-vega-plot/index.html#vega-plot). That gives you a tremendous amount of customizability. You would then put that chart in a Quiver dashboard and embed that dashboard in the Workshop app.